# invalid use of rs.filter property?

Tags: sql, mysql, excel, vba, adodb

i am connecting to mysql using adodb from excel

i am doing:

```
dpath = Range("B2").Text
atime = Trim(Range("B3").Text)
rtime = Trim(Range("B4").Text)
lcalib = Trim(Range("B5").Text)
aname = Trim(Range("B6").Text)
rname = Trim(Range("B7").Text)
bstate = Trim(Range("B8").Text)


rs.Filter "datapath=dpath and analystname=aname and reportname=rname and batchstate"
```

but it's giving me an error that it is invalid use of filter property

what is the correct way to use the filter property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter is a property, plus you're using external variables in your string.  The filter will have no knowledge of them.  You need something like:

```
rs.Filter = "datapath='" + dpath + "' and analystname='" + aname + "' and reportname='" + rname + "' and batchstate='" + batchstate + "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter is a property, not a method, so you have to assign to it, not call it. Basically you're missing an equals sign: it should be `rs.Filter = ...`